# Iterate through dictionary with foreach loop and fetch all key/value pairs with value subset items

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, concurrentdictionary

I have a concurrent dictionary that I am storing key/value pairs in. The complexity here is that the values are not single objects like string or integer, they are a collection of items that are added using a class model. It seems looking at the debug, I am able to add the items to the dictionary successfully, but the issue I have is not knowing how to read these items when iterating through the dictionary from another thread. I simply want to read all the key/value pairs, including all the items and add them to an array that I can pass back to the user through JsonResult/Ajax.

My AlarmEngine Class:

```
public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> concurrentDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

public class Alarm
{
    public int AlarmId { get; set; }
    public string AlarmName { get; set; }
    public string AlarmDescription { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationRoleId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeActivated { get; set; }
}
```

An extract from the method where I add items to the dictionary:

```
concurrentDictionary.TryAdd(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), new Alarm 
                {
                    DateTimeActivated = DateTime.Now,
                    ApplicationRoleId = applicationRoleId,
                    AlarmId = alarmId,
                    AlarmName = alarmName,
                    AlarmDescription = description,
                }); // I'm using datetime as the key as this is unique form each key/value pair added.
```

My AlarmList MVC Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public Task<IActionResult> FetchAlarmsListAsync()
{

    // Enumeration is thread-safe in ConcurrentDictionary.
    foreach (var item in AlarmEngine.concurrentDictionary)
    {
        // How do I access the key and value pairs here?
        // Note each value contains a subset of items
        // i want to access all items stored
    }

    return new JsonResult(Array containing all keys and value items);
}
```

If it's better to read through the whole dictionary and store all keys/value(with sub items) to a list before returning to the user as an JSON array, this would be an acceptable solution for me as well, just keep in mind I want to do this as efficiently as possible to minimize converting from one form to another too many times. Items will be added and removed to the dictionary from other threads, but this particular bit of my application i.e. iteration through the dictionary is just for readonly purposes and it doesn't really matter to me if the contents have changed whilst reading through it, it's just to put together a list of alarms relevant/active at the time of the query.

Comment: What is the specific issue you are having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the data as the right class, do not use `object`

```
public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Alarm> concurrentDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Alarm>();
//                                          ^^^ 

public class Alarm
{
    public int AlarmId { get; set; }
    public string AlarmName { get; set; }
    public string AlarmDescription { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationRoleId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeActivated { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can access the properties of the alarm.

```
// Enumeration is thread-safe in Dictionary.
foreach (var item in AlarmEngine.concurrentDictionary)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(item.Key);  // which is the datetime
    Trace.WriteLine(item.Value.AlarmName);
    // How do I access the key and value pairs here?
    // Note each value contains a subset of items
    // i want to access all items stored
}
```

---

One thing you should change is not storing the DateTime as string.

```
public static ConcurrentDictionary<DateTime, Alarm> concurrentDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<DateTime, Alarm>();
```

Comment: Ah I see now, I was referencing a generic <object> in my dictionary rather than using the actual class "Alarm". I'm now able to resolve the value items successfully, many thanks for your help.

Answer (score -2):

If these resources are shared amoung multiple clients/threads and mostly the clients are reading. I would suggest a [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=netframework-4.8). It allows multiple readers and one writer.

This way the jsons can be generated parallel. A `ConcurrentX` is usefull passing resources to others thread *(like passing ownership)* or just *share* simple typed data.

```
private static ReaderWriterLockSlim cacheLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
```

---

```
[HttpGet]
public Task<IActionResult> FetchAlarmsListAsync()
{
    cacheLock.EnterReadLock();
    try
    {
        // Enumeration is thread-safe in Dictionary.
        foreach (var item in AlarmEngine.normalDictionary)
        {
            // How do I access the key and value pairs here?
            // Note each value contains a subset of items
            // i want to access all items stored
        }

        return new JsonResult(Array containing all keys and value items);
    }
    finally
    {
        cacheLock.ExitReadLock();
    }
}
```

---

```
cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
try
{
    normalDictionary.TryAdd(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), new Alarm 
    {
        DateTimeActivated = DateTime.Now,
        ApplicationRoleId = applicationRoleId,
        AlarmId = alarmId,
        AlarmName = alarmName,
        AlarmDescription = description,
    }); // I'm using datetime as the key as this is unique form each key/value pair added.
}
finally
{
    cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
}
```

---

It's even possible to cache the json result when the dictionary isn't changed, but you should only do such thing when it is a problem.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, the bit I'm struggling with is not knowing how to access the values in the loop because they are not storing single objects like a string or integer, key/value pair will contain subest of value items. Example Key = datetime, value = { AlarmId, AlarmName, AlarmDescription } etc

Comment: This is not about data accessing, it's about safe accessing the data. That's why you need a separate lock. A ConcurrentDictionary is only concurrent on it's collection, not the data it contains. So use a normal Dictionary instead of a concurrent one. When you access any information stored in the dictionary (key's, value's (even complex object)) must be done within the readwriterlock. After you created the json, the lock can be released.

Comment: So are we saying that concurrent dictionary is unable to store a complex object? The reason I opted for concurrent dictionary is that multiple threads will be adding items, multiple threads need to read the contents. The MVC Controller will only be reading, but items are still being added concurrently from other threads. I would need to see some example code in how the value items can be retrieved, please see me comments in foreach loop section, thanks

Comment: Yes, like I said, a ConcurrentDictionary is only safe on it's collection not the data. _(Only value typed data is safe because when reading data it make a copy.)_ I only use a ConcurrentQueue (or whatever) to put in an item (like a fire and forget) and never touch it within the added thread. Some other thread can read the information. So I don't think a ConcurrentDictionary suits your application.

Comment: When each alarm is added to the dictionary, it will never be modified. The only actions will ever be to add a new alarm to the dictionary, or simply remove it from the dictionary. Would this still cause any concern?

Comment: No, if you never change the data, it won't be any problem. Only when you change any data (when already added), a concurrentdictionary is not the right choice. I still advise the ReadWriterLock, because it is more scalable and if you ever decide to change the current data, you probably would forget to change the concurrentdictionary.

Comment: OK, so concurrent should work in my particular environment. Would you be so kind to edit your answer with an example in how I access/read these stored items? this is the main reason for me asking the question. Please see comments shown in the foreach loop example, many thanks

Comment: I've added another answer

Comment: I downvoted this answer because the OP mentions use of concurrent dictionary and doesn’t care that items might be added while trying to pull a snapshot. Thus the reader lock is actually detrimental in this case.

Comment: @theMayer is right. The entire point of `ConcurrentDictionary` is thread agnostic operation.

Comment: I missed the _"iteration through the dictionary is just for readonly purposes and it doesn't really matter to me if the contents have changed whilst reading"_